# Does JSON.parse call a callback when deserializing the string?

Tags: javascript, json

`JSON.stringify` helper in JavaScript (from what I know) when invoked on a class instance, looks for `toJSON()` method and calls it for a given instance automatically and then uses its output as a value. I wonder if there's a similar mechanism for an opposite operation? Does `JSON.parse` has any default callback that it would call when deserializing the string?

Comment: A quick look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) should answer this

Comment: So I downvote these for lack of (documented) research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [`JSON.parse()` has a reviver parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Parameters) that can be passed in when deserialising.

Here is an example usage

```js
const json = `{
  "a": "1", 
  "b": "true", 
  "c": "foo", 
  "d": "world", 
  "e": "2020-12-26",
  "f": "bar"
}`;

function reviver(key, value) {
  if (key === "a") //convert to number
    return Number(value);
  
  if (key === "b") //convert to boolean
    return value === "true";
  
  if (key === "c") //change value entirely
    return "hello";
  
  if (key === "e") //convert to a different object
    return new Date(value);
  
  if (key === "f") //omit key-value pair
    return;
  
  return value; //preserve anything else
}

const obj = JSON.parse(json, reviver);

console. log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes; you can supply a "reviver" function (see the [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)) which you could potentially use to recognise special data in your JSON and parse it accordingly. For example, dates are converted to strings by `JSON.stringify`, and `JSON.parse` leaves them as such so it returns a string which is the output of `Date.toJSON`. By specifying a "reviver" function though, we can detect our date object (by its key in my example - you might also detect the output of your `toJSON` function in the value) and return a `Date` object rather than a string:

```js
const obj = {
  id: 1,
  date: new Date(2020, 12, 25, 15, 4, 5)
}

const json = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(json);

let parsedObj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(parsedObj.date.toString());

parsedObj = JSON.parse(json, (key, value) =>
  key == 'date' ? new Date(value) : value
);

console.log(parsedObj.date.toString());
```